# How to access the other drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

My case is as follows:

- SSD: On which windows is installed.
- HDD: Used as an extra storage space. Doesn't have any OS installed on it but has a few partitions.

Now I want to install Ubuntu on my SSD has the only OS and don't want to use Windows anymore. So I will be installing it on SSD because of speed but I will backup all files in the hard drive and I don't want to format it.

So will I be able to access the hard drive after installing Ubuntu on SSD as the hard drive contains lots of important files and also the backed-up files?

[image]

Comment: Linux NTFS driver can read & write NTFS, if you have turned off hibernation & fast start up in Windows. Otherwise it is locked up with a hibernation flag. But if no Windows, you should not use NTFS. There are no real tools in Linux to run chkdks, defrag or make other repairs to NTFS. You should backup data & convert to ext4 or other Linux format. Many find one Windows app or game they must have that does not work in Ubuntu. So best to fully back up Windows. And if really wanting to keep NTFS, make a Windows repair flash drive and/or installer just for repairs.

Comment: Yes you can use your old drive without change; but you didn't provide file-system details so advice is *generic* in nature and I'd ensure you read oldfred's comment.

Comment: @oldfred I have the files like pdf, docs, some react and flutter projects, and also some photos. Will the same be accessible directly or some modifications are required. And yes the hard drive was formatted by the default Format of NTFS when I installed Windows on SSD. I have attached an image for clarity in question. The C is SSD and the rest are hard drive partitions.

Comment: You must turn off Windows fast startup/hibernation or NTFS is read only. Otherwise it will just work until you need NTFS repairs which you cannot do from Linux. Chkdsk, defrag, etc. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Thanks, I have done it